# Are foreground applications allocated more system resources than others?

Tags: macos, finder, software-update, file-transfer

Sometimes it seems like Time Machine backups, file transfers, and software updates speed up after focusing their windows.

Is this just psychological or an actual feature?

Comment: Can you test using the same files and timing it?

Comment: It's a feature, though I'm not savvy enough to formulate an answer with citations. Apps have a foreground & background Yield time - how much 'spare' time they give up to other apps. This may be to do with unix [nice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix)) but that's where my knowledge falls down. My knowledge begins & ends with an online game I used to run support for. The yeild times were user-modifiable through a 'hidden' parameter in the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most probably not psychological as multiple things affect the allocation of system resources, and being a foreground window is one of them.

In general all processes (and even threads) running on a system has a priority, which is used to determine the amount of CPU resources made available to it. If you open a normal GUI program, it will start with a priority of 46. If it is the foreground window, the priority is increased by 1 to 47.

The actual range of priorities on a live system is much larger as other things factor into the process priority. They range from 0 (lowest priority) to usually 97 (queue in a real time process). For ordinary programs you run, you'll usually see priorities such as 20 (utility program), 31 (base priority), 46 (background) and 47 (foreground).

You might be experiencing the impact of a feature known as "App Nap". It essentially slows down applications that the system thinks the user is not actively using in order to speed save energy and/or improve performance of other apps.

Specially it targets apps that are:

- not the foreground (selected) app
- hasn't recently updated visible information on screen
- isn't playing audio
- isn't using OpenGL 3D graphics
- isn't actively managing energy usage using IOKit/NSProcessInfo

When those conditions are in place, the application can be put into App Nap. If you look at Activity Monitor in the Energy tab, you'll see a column named "App Nap". If this says "Yes", the app is napping.

When an application is in App Nap it runs slower due to a reduction of its CPU priority, throttling of I/O and throtting of timers.

You can read more about App Nap in Apple's documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/AppNap.html

As far as I recall, the priority of an App Nap'ed program is 4.

Comment: Apps have been doing this since long before App Nap was invented.

Comment: Sure - nothing prevents an app itself from lowering its own priority. You can also lower an app's priority yourself. That wasn't the question here though. Are you thinking of anything specific?

Comment: The only real reference I have is the game I used to work with - with user-settable yields. It would never nap [or it would lose net connection & timeout, of course] but you could set it to barely tick over & allow everything else to run at full speed, even if it was still visible behind other windows, so still running visible OpenGL etc.

Comment: That's something special for that game - it is not a general thing that programs have foreground and background "yield times". That sort of thing is only for thing is only for things scheduled in real time mode, which you won't see with Time Machine, file transfers, and software updates...